# Batch Change Directory to New Directory

Tags: batch-file, directory, copy, mkdir

I have a batch script that creates a new directory with time and date stamp;

```
mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\CraftBukkit\World Backup\CraftBukkit World - %date:/=.% - %time::=.%"
```

Then I want to have the script copy three folders into that directory. I can easily copy them with xcopy, I just don't know how to pull the new directory that I just made to show xcopy where to put the three folders. 
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe first store the directory name in a variable, use the variable to create a directory and use the variable again for xcopy..

Comment: @RBK Make your comment an answer.

Comment: @ProfPickle, thanks, I've made it to an answer.

Comment: @JoeSweeney, you could accept the answer so that it's helpful for people looking at it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first store the directory name in a variable, use the variable to create a directory and use the variable again for xcopy.